# Check if two users liked each others items

Tags: mysql, sql

I have three tables:

**users**

```
+----+------+
| id | name |
+----+------+
|  1 | Foo  |
|  2 | Bar  |
|  3 | La   |
+----+------+
```

**items**

```
+----+-------+
| id | owner |
+----+-------+
|  1 |     2 |
|  2 |     1 |
|  3 |     2 |
+----+-------+
```

**votes**

```
+----+------+---------+---------+
| id | vote | user_id | item_id |
+----+------+---------+---------+
|  1 |    1 |       1 |       1 |
|  2 |    1 |       2 |       2 |
|  3 |   -1 |       3 |       1 |
|  4 |    1 |       1 |       2 |
|  5 |   -1 |       3 |       2 |
+----+------+---------+---------+
```

Now, I wish to write a query that checks wether two specific user_ids like each others items.

I wish to get the ids of the two items that matches.

What is the most efficient way you could write this query? I have created a sqlfiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c09fa

Comment: what result do you want a boolean(num row) or recods of liking?

Comment: Have you actually tried writing the query for yourself? Please show us what effort you have already made.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would first do a simple join to get a list of users and the users thing they have liked.

```
SELECT user_id AS id1, items.owner AS id2 FROM votes
       JOIN items ON items.id=item_id;
```

Which will give a table with 2 ids. Then join this table with itself and check each are equal. So

```
SELECT * FROM temp t1 JOIN temp t2
    WHERE t1.id1=t2.id2 AND t1.id2=t2.id1
```

Putting the 2 together you would get:

```
SELECT * FROM
  (SELECT user_id AS id1, items.owner AS id2 FROM votes
JOIN items ON items.id=item_id) table1
JOIN
  (SELECT user_id AS id1, items.owner AS id2 FROM votes
JOIN items ON items.id=item_id) table2
WHERE
  table1.id1=table2.id2 AND table1.id2=table2.id1;
```

You weren't clear about what sort of outputs you were looking for but that will output a table with 2 columns where everyone in it has a mutual like.

There may be a more efficient method that doesn't involve subqueries though.